# No "moveObject" function in AWS PHP S3 SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have one system with the s3cmd python function installed and it offers an "move" command "ie: s3cmd mv s3://bucket/object s3://newBucket/object" type syntax.

I'm building an intranet site for object manipulation functions and from what I can tell, the sdk doesn't offer an moveObject function in the s3client.php class.  Am I missing something here, or do I have to perform the copyObject function then clean up with a deleteObject call to old bucket/key after I've copied the bucket/key to the newBucket/newKey location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "MoveObject" operation in Amazon S3. If s3cmd supports this operation, then it must be doing a `CopyObject` and `DeleteObject` under the hood.